# Mule ESB: Generate Same and Dynamic Correlation ID in Different Flow

Tags: mule, esb, correlation

currently I am working with Mule ESB. For now, I have 2 flow, lets say Flow 1 and Flow 2. What I need to do is generating the same correlation ID in different flow. The value of the correlation ID itself should be dynamic. I mean, the correlation ID when I run the program on the first try and correlation ID when I run the program on the second time should be different.

For example: when I send first request to my inbound the correlation ID is abcdef (in both flow 1 and flow 2), then after the first request is finish, I send the second request and the correlation ID for the second request is: xyz123455 (in both flow 1 and flow 2).

How to achieve that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do anything particular to propagate the correlation ID between flows: Mule does it for you. Also, Mule generates a unique ID for each inbound message so you can just use it as the correlation ID.

Here is an example:

```
<flow name="firstFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/test" />

    <!-- No correlation ID yet -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="CID: #[message.correlationId]" />

    <!-- Use the message unique ID as its correlation ID -->
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" value="#[message.id]" />

    <!-- Correlation ID is set -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="CID: #[message.correlationId]" />

    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="second.flow" />
</flow>

<flow name="secondFlow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="second.flow" />

    <!-- Correlation ID is propagated -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="CID: #[message.correlationId]" />
</flow>
```

If you `curl http://localhost:8080/test` you'll see in the logs something similar to:

```
09:18:58,824 INFO connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] CID: null
09:18:58,831 INFO  connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] CID: 1c51391c-e35f-11e3-926a-9979ff687cfa
09:18:58,847 INFO  connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02 [org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager] Initialising: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.11119625'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
09:18:58,848 INFO  connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02 [org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager] Starting: 'connector.VM.mule.default.dispatcher.11119625'. Object is: VMMessageDispatcher
09:18:58,860 INFO  secondFlow.stage1.02 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] CID: 1c51391c-e35f-11e3-926a-9979ff687cfa
```

As you can see, the correlation ID is propagated automatically.

Comment: the problem is, i dont want to use vm. The inbound endpoint of my second flow is wmq. And the outbound of endpoint of the first flow is another wmq. Both wmq in 1st and 2nd flow is different. Outbound wmq (WMQ A) in 1st flow is used for write and inbound wmq (WMQ B) in 2nd flow is only used for read.

Comment: Your initial question didn't mention that. I believe my answer is acceptable in that context. As far as WMQ is concerned, it's up to whatever receives the message and responds to it to carry the correlation ID to the response message. Mule will put the correlation in the standard `JMSCorrelationId` message property.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate dynamically correlation ID in one flow (by say `UUID` class), store it as a `session variable` and use it in another flow.

Comment: the problem is, i dont want to use vm. The inbound endpoint of my second flow is wmq. And the outbound of endpoint of the first flow is another wmq. Both wmq in 1st and 2nd flow is different. Outbound wmq (WMQ A) in 1st flow is used for write and inbound wmq (WMQ B) in 2nd flow is only used for read.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution :- just store the correlation ID that is generated dynamically in a session variable and extract the value of the session variable in the other flow that required the same correlation ID

Comment: the problem is, i dont want to use vm. The inbound endpoint of my second flow is wmq. And the outbound of endpoint of the first flow is another wmq. Both wmq in 1st and 2nd flow is different. Outbound wmq (WMQ A) in 1st flow is used for write and inbound wmq (WMQ B) in 2nd flow is only used for read.

Comment: @Anirban Sen Chowdhary How does your answer adds more value or different than mine?

Comment: Sorry .. I haven't seen your answer while posting mine ... pls ignore